# How to compare list in Python with some class using imlicator in?

Tags: python, list, class, compare

I would like to compare list which contain some class using implicator in. Code below:

```
class Word:
    def __init__(self, p_name):
        self.name = p_name
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.name == other.name
    def __str__(self):
        return "_name_: " + self.name
t1 = []
t1.append(Word("John"))     
t2 = []
t2.append(Word("John"))
if t1 in t2:
    print("the same")
```

I got an error that "list has no attribute 'name'". I know that I can write some loops but I would like to use implicator in if it is possible in such situation.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *implicator in*. Can you elaborate on that or provide a link to something that explains what you mean by that?

Comment: Are you looking for *intersections* here? `t1` is a list here, but I think you want to find if there are any elements in `t1` that also appear in `t2`?

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
if t1 in t2:
    print("the same")
```

Should be one of these:

```
# Check if a single word is in t2.
w = Word("John")
if w in t2:
    print("the same")

# Check if any element of t1 is in t2.
if any(w in t2 for w in t1):
    print("the same")

# Check if all elements of t1 are in t2.
if all(w in t2 for w in t1):
    print("the same")
```

You should not be checking if one list is in another list. You either want to check if a particular item is in a list, or you want to compare all of the items in `t1` with the items in `t2`.

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return isinstance(other, Word) and self.name == other.name
```

It would also be a good idea to add a check to `__eq__` that `other` is a `Word`. Your code blows up because `other` is a list not a `Word`, and so the `other.name` lookup fails.